# coffeescript scope of variable assignment vs property assignment in object's other properties

Tags: coffeescript, scope

I'm writing some widgets for [Ubersicht](https://github.com/felixhageloh/uebersicht). It uses a node.js server and treats each `.coffee` file as a standalone widget object. I'm having issues defining constant settings to be used throughout one file. Currently I know of two ways to define this type of constant at the top of the file.

```
# Way 1
foo_1 = true
bar_1 = false
# Way 2
foo_2: true
bar_2: false
```

Further down in the same file either a property is assigned as a string or as a function. Each of the above two ways of defining an option only works in one of the two property types.

```
staticProperty: """Output #{foo_1} works here
but output of #{foo_2} doesn't work
"""

methodProperty: (input) -> 
  if foo_1 # Raises foo_1 is not defined
  if @foo_1 # foo_1 is undefined which is expected
  if @foo_2 # This works fine
```

I understand that way 2 add to the object's properties, but I'm not too sure how the way 1 assignment works given that the file is essentially defining an object. Can you explain this?

Also is there a way to define a variable that can be accessed from both places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll look at a big ugly example to see what's going on:

```
class C
    a: 6
    b: @::a
    c = 11
    d: c
    @e = 23
    f: @e
    g: -> @a
    h: -> C::b
    i: -> c
    j: -> @constructor.e
```

`a` is a normal old property, in JavaScript it looks like:

```
C.prototype.a = 6;
```

`b` is also a normal old property that is attached to the prototype; here:

```
b: @::a
```

`@` is the class itself so in JavaScript this is:

```
C.prototype.b = C.prototype.a
```

and everything works just fine.

`c` is sort of a private variable. In JavaScript it looks like this:

```
var C = (function() {
  function C() {}
  var c = 11;
  //...
})();
```

I've included more JavaScript context here so that you can see `c`'s scope. `c` is visible to anything inside the definition of `C` but nowhere else.

`d` is another property that is on the prototype and looks like this in JavaScript:

```
C.prototype.d = c
```

This assignment happens inside the SIF wrapper that is used to build the class so `var c = 11` is visible here.

`e` is a class property and in JavaScript is just:

```
C.e = 23;
```

`f` is another property on the prototype. `@` is the class itself in this context (just like in `b`):

```
f: @e
```

so we can get at `e` as `@e` and the JavaScript looks like:

```
C.prototype.f = C.e;
```

The `g` and `h` methods should be pretty clear. The `i` method works because it is a closure inside the SIF that is used to define `C`:

```
C.prototype.i = function() { return c; };
```

The `j` method works because it uses the standard [`constructor` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) to get back to `C` itself.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/tg8krgh2/

---

Applying all that to your situation,

```
class Pancakes
  foo_1 = true
  foo_2: true
```

We see that you can use either approach if you reference things properly:

```
staticProperty: """Output #{foo_1} works here
and so does #{@::foo_2}
"""

methodProperty: (input) -> 
  # foo_1 should work fine in here.
  # @foo_1 is undefined which is expected
  # @foo_2 works fine
```

I'm not sure why you're having a problem referencing `foo_1` inside your `methodProperty`, it should work fine and [does work fine](http://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20C%0A%20%20p%20%3D%20true%0A%20%20m%3A%20-%3E%20console.log('hi')%20if(p)%0A%0Ac%20%3D%20new%20C%0Ac.m()) with the current version of CoffeeScript.

Comment: This is very informative and clears a lot of stuff up. There are a few things that Ubersicht does to the object. Firstly the .coffee file is read in as text and put through `eval`. This should not be an issue. What I believe the issue is that the object is copied over to a new object like so `new[k] = v for k, v of old` and thus it looses all private variables. That is why `foo_1` is undefined. Trying with `@::foo_2` gives a `cannot read property 'foo_2' of undefined`. This I don't understand yet.

Comment: The `@::foo_2` error could be caused by the copying in some contexts, if Ubersicht is just copying properties with a `for ... of` loop then you'll lose track of the prototype (AKA `@::`). It could also be loosing track of `@` if it is treating the methods as plain functions.