# $timeout cannot find my variable

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

Ok using Angular and Coffeescript here the following works:

```
angular.module 'someApp'
  .factory 'someFactory', ($timeout) -> new class SomeClass
    constructor: ->
      @humans = 1

    findHuman: ->
      $timeout((=>@humans+=1), 1000)
```

Which is fine I guess but I'd like to have the @humans+=1 part somewhere else.

So why does this not work?

```
angular.module 'someApp'
  .factory 'someFactory', ($timeout) -> new class SomeClass
    constructor: ->
      @humans = 1

    findHuman: ->
      $timeout(addOneHuman, 1000)

    addOneHuman = =>
      @humans+=1
```

Testing around with console.log or $log, adding @'s here and there, -> instead of => sometimes the variable humans is NaN, sometimes it is undefined.

What do I have to do to make this work? :)

Comment: I don't know Angular that well so I can't say much on that side of things but `addOneHuman = => ...` is more like a private *function*, `addOneHuman: => ...` would be a *method*.

Comment: Holy crap it works. I mean, I had to do $timeout(@addOneHuman) then but the : => thing worked. Thanks a lot. (How do I mark this as solved?)

Comment: I fleshed that comment out into a real answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the Angular side of things that well but I think your problem is that this:

```
addOneHuman = =>
```

doesn't do what you think it does. Something like this:

```
class C
  f = ->
  m: ->
```

creates `f` as essentially a private *function* within `C`. The JavaScript version is equivalent to:

```
var C = (function() {
  function C() {}
  var f = function() {};
  C.prototype.m = function() {};
  return C;
})();
```

so `f` is just a variable that references a function and `f` is in scope for anything in `C`. Changing it to:

```
f = =>
```

doesn't do anything because there is no `this` that applies when `f` is defined. On the other hand, `m` is a method (note the `C.prototype.m` in the JavaScript version) so there is an applicable `this` and `m: =>` can do something useful.

You just want your `addOneHuman` to be a *method* rather than a plain old function:

```
addOneHuman: =>
# ---------^
```

There might be something useful to you in a couple of my other answers:

- [**coffeescript scope of variable assignment vs property assignment in object's other properties**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27350176/479863)
- [**How to make method private and inherit it in Coffeescript?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10612530/479863)